# Yii2: How to read a cookie, which was set by JavaScript

Tags: yii2

I set a cookie in web/js/site.js:

```
$.cookie("sidebar", "hidden", { path: '/' });
```

I read the cookie with PHP:

```
$sidebar_toggle_state = $_COOKIE['sidebar'];
```

Is it possible to use also the Yii Request Component to read such cookies? The following code doesn't read the cookie:

```
$sidebar_toggle_state = Yii::$app->request()->cookies()->getValue('sidebar', '');
```

See: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html#cookies

When I set a new cookie through the Yii Response Component:

```
Yii::$app->response->cookies->add(new yii\web\Cookie([
    'name' => 'sidebar',
    'value' => 'hidden',
]));
```

Then the value of the cookie looks like this (because the cookie is protected):

```
3976220a3c8e46bb641aef1da3accfb1652bffd5bb9de503a9d6882e8a69f6f9a%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A7%3A%22sidebar%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A6%3A%22hidden%22%3B%7D
```

Such cookie can the Yii Request Component read. But can it read also unprotected cookies?

Or, is it possible to set the Yii protected cookies with JavasSript / jQuery (without using AJAX)?

Comment: There is a JavaScript API, which enables to read cookies protected by Yii2: https://github.com/Requilence/yii2-js-cookie But the API can not set cookies, because "You can't set protected cookies in JS because of impletation of signing algorithm will be insecure on the client side".

Comment: have tried this i\Yii::$app->getRequest()->getCookies()->has('cookie_name'); for checking

Comment: @NuriddinRashidov Yes, I have tried: if (Yii::$app->getRequest()->getCookies()->has('sidebar')) { ... (in several variants). And I have also tried to view all cookies by var_dump(Yii::$app->request->cookies); But with no positive results.

Comment: I guess you wanted to show / hide the sidebar with that cookie. So why don't you just show/hide the sidebar with js by reading the cookie on document ready?

Otherwise they also write in the tutorial you have linked in your post 
`Note: Cookie validation only protects cookie values from being modified. If a cookie fails the validation, you may still access it through $_COOKIE. This is because third-party libraries may manipulate cookies in their own way, which does not involve cookie validation.` 
Sou you just have to use php code $_COOKIE directly to get the cookies set by js.

Comment: @BHoft You are correct. I want to show/hide sidebar, which is part of the adminLTE theme. The theme is installed in the vendor directory, which I do not want to change, because after the next update, will be my changes overwritten. If the sidebar should be visible or not is controlled through the tag: <body class="sidebar_collapse"> So the most direct way is to read the cookie with php and then add "sidebar_collapse" to the class attribute, if the cookie has the value "hidden". I can also manipulate the tag <body> with JS, after the page is loaded, but it will collide with adminLTE JS.

Comment: Did you check what i also have written? Have you checked if the cookie is available through `$_COOKIE` ?

Comment: @BHoft  That is how I do it recently: $sidebar_toggle_state = $_COOKIE['sidebar'];

Comment: @AntonínSlejška And? exactly this is mentioned in the tutorial. Protected cookies are handled through the request and reponse because yii\web\Request::$enableCookieValidation is per default set to true. Other cookies have to be checked or set by $_COOKIE if cookie validation is enabled and yii\web\Request::$cookieValidationKey is set. So everything works as expected.

Answer (score 8):

To read a cookie set by Javascript, you have, in configurations, `config/web.php` to set some request components properties to be `false` like the following:

```
'components' => [
        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'SomeRandomStringChars',
            'enableCookieValidation' => false,
            'enableCsrfValidation' => false,
        ],
```

This will allow reading cookies that have been set using Javascript like the following:

```
Yii::$app->getRequest()->getCookies()->getValue('theme');
```

## Warning!

The above solution may has **security issues**, because we canceled the `enableCookieValidation` and `enableCsrfValidation` for all cookies. So there is another solution that allows jumping those validations for a specific cookie, suppose the `theme` cookie that we just have used in the example above, we will utilize the second parameter of `getValue()` method, i.e the default value, like the following:

```
Yii::$app->getRequest()->getCookies()->getValue('theme', (isset($_COOKIE['theme']))? $_COOKIE['theme']: 'theme')
```

The above solution will let you keeping both, `enableCookieValidation` and `enableCsrfValidation` to be `true` and only bypass them for a specific cookie.